# Recursive structure definition in C, error "forward declaration"

Tags: c, recursion

I want do declare my structure as a recursive one. So what I did until now looks like this:

```
 typedef struct {

 char *string;
 struct my_struct **children; //I want a list of children, therefore pointer to pointer
 int child_num;
 } my_struct;
```

But when I then try to initialize it like this:

```
my_struct *alig;
alig = malloc(sizeof(my_struct)*1);
alig->child_num = 5;
alig->string = malloc(sizeof(char)*9);
strncpy(alig->string, "AAACGTCA", 8);

alig->children = malloc(sizeof(my_struct*)*alig->child_num);

int j;
for (j = 0; j < alig->child_num; j++) {
    alig->children[j] = malloc(sizeof(my_struct)*1);
    alig->children[j]->string = malloc(sizeof(char)*9); // *********error ********
}
```

I get the error:
"./structurs.h:27:13: note: forward declaration of 'struct my_struct' "

As well as this error at the marked line:
main.c:56:22: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct my_struct'

Does someone now where my mistake is??

Comment: (apart from the typedef) your usage of `strncpy()` is wrong. (use of strncpy() is **always** wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `struct my_struct` in your code, your `struct` is an anonymous `typedef`, you need it to be like this

```
typedef struct my_struct {
     char *string;
     struct my_struct **children;
     int child_num;
} my_struct;
```

Or even

```
typedef struct my_struct my_struct;
struct my_struct {
     char *string;
     my_struct **children;
     int child_num;
};
```

Comment: I am blind -.-!!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
 typedef struct {

 char *string;
 struct my_struct **children; //I want a list of children, therefore pointer to pointer
 int child_num;
 } my_struct;
```

should be

```
 typedef struct my_struct{

 char *string;
 struct my_struct **children; //I want a list of children, therefore pointer to pointer
 int child_num;
 } my_struct;
```

As said by **@iharob** there is no struct `my_struct` in your code and compiler is complaining about it you first have a struct my_struct has shown and then have a typedef for your struct

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
typedef struct {
 char *string;
 struct my_struct **children; 
 int child_num;
 } my_struct;
```

**does not** define a `struct` called `struct my_struct`, rather , it `typedef`s `my_struct` to be an alias of an *unnamed* struct. So you cannot use `struct my_struct` in your code. Either

Either

- You need to put the `typedef` before the structure definiion.

or

- You need to use a *named* `struct`.